# Theoretical results regarding the size of the training set for neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Have you ever seen anything like a theoretical approach for determining the optimal size (or perhaps some bounds for it) of the training set for a neural network?

I know that this is a very broad question, since the optimality should be considered with respect to a specific loss function; and there are several kinds of neural networks. Please feel free to consider the specific cases which you know about, if necessary - although I am particularly interested in perceptrons with 1 hidden layer for classification, reducing the cross-entropy loss function.-

I would like to find something more rigorous than an empirical comparison of the classification errors over training and validation data for different sizes of the training set.

Comment: Are we assuming that the variables are Independent and identically distributed random variables. And are the training examples are independent and well distributed?

Comment: @show_stopper yes, you may assume all that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you ever seen anything like a theoretical approach for
>   determining the optimal size (or perhaps some bounds for it) of the
>   training set for a neural network?

What you are referring to is the topic of computational learning theory. One way to measure it is to use Vapnik-Chervonenkis dimension.

There are some results on VC dimension bounds of neural networks: [Vapnik-Chervonenkis Dimension of Neural
Nets](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7de1/b823a4e766bfb8152fe5c12b4cb2d2fd5810.pdf)